# Xcode IOS Create 3 buttons to replace keyboard and text box

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-uno, ios9.1

I am using an app to lock, unlock, and open the trunk of my car. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to modify the Xcode project so there are 3 buttons. Basically right now if I type "U" then enter- the car unlocks, "L" then enter- the car locks, and "T" then enter- the trunk opens. I want to add three buttons that simulate these three things and eliminate the typing all together. If you want to see my adruino or xcode project code I can upload those. I have put some code about the text box below.

```
    BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSString *text = textField.text;
    NSNumber *form = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];

    NSString *s;
    NSData *d;

    if (text.length > 16)
    s = [text substringToIndex:16];
     else
        s = text;

    d = [s dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if (bleShield.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
    [bleShield write:d];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:text, TEXT_STR, form, FORM, nil];
    [tableData addObject:dict];
    [_tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    NSLog(@"%f", _tableView.contentOffset.y);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

textField.text = @"";

return YES;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you getting the letters from a text field currently?  All you need to do is put three buttons with an action method that sends the appropriate command.  Can you show *some* code?

Comment: @Paulw11     Hey thanks for the quick reply! I am actually new to this so Im just going to kinda explain what my code is doing. I have an arduino that has code on it to do certain things when it receives any of those 3 letters. The letters are typed into a text field as of right now using a key board and then sent using the send button on the keyboard. Here is a link to the GitHub repository my code is very similar to this: https://github.com/RedBearLab/iOS/tree/master/Examples/BLEChat_Central_iOS/SimpleChat

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller probably has a `textFieldShouldReturn` method which is taking the string value from the text field and building a parameter to a call that initiates sending the command. If not this method then perhaps its action method linked to the text field.

You'll need to duplicate parts of that code into a method that receives a string parameter instead of taking it from the text field, say named `sendLockCommand:(NSString *)commandString` (assuming you're coding in Objective-C, also like that repo).

Make action methods for your buttons, something like `lockDoors`, `unlockDoors`, `openTrunk`, in each call `[self sendLockCommand:@"L"]`, each with the appropriate string. Wire up the buttons to those actions and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I'm out right now but I will try it when I get home and will let you if that works. I might need your help because I'm new to Xcode.   Thanks

Comment: I edited in what was in the textFieldShoudReturn area. I would really appreciate if you could walk me through how to do all of this as I have no clue how to.    Thanks so much! @smallduck

Comment: Hey I already tried those couldn't seem to find anything. Is there one in particular that would help me?